# change attribute in button In symfony 2

Tags: symfony

i need add class and id to button in the form in Symfony 2. I use this doucmentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/submit.html#attr

```
add('send','submit',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'submit_btn','id'=>'submit',"style"=>"font-weight: bold")))
                 ->add('reset','reset',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'submit_btn','id'=>'reset',"style"=>"font-weight: bold")))
                 ->getForm();
```

But it doesn't work
I I will be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

Better way add your class and attr in twig file.

```
 {{form_widget(form.eventName,{ 'attr': {'class': "span12"}})}}
```

Comment: It's work ,thank.But why why method in createFormBuilder dosn't work?

Comment: You can do it with FormBuilder. Add this to the array in your FormBuilder:

      'attr'=> array('class'=>'span2')

Comment: But Remember, you are setting frontend source code in your FormType which is not a great solution. The best solution is to put it in your twig file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any bundles that might be overriding the 'attr' option in your formbuilder code? I personally render all buttons manually, because I use the mopabootstrap bundle, and it messes up the alignment if I use formbuilder to render the buttons.

Comment: I' m not use any other bundles, only standart witch packed in symfony